# How to paste into emacs --no-window-system without auto-indent?

Tags: emacs, paste

If I paste a piece of code from the browser to `emacs -nw` with middle mouse button, or Ctrl+Shift+v (in gnome-terminal paste from clipboard), it's incorrectly indented.

Original code:

```
for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    j = j + i;
    print j;
}
```

Becomes:

```
for (i=0; i<=10; i++) {
          j = j + i;
                print j;
                    }
```

In vim one would turn off auto-indent. In emacs I tried 2 ways that doesn't work:

Method 1:

Configure ctrl+y to use PRIMARY selection in ~/.emacs

```
(setq x-select-enable-primary t)
```

And try to paste with Ctrl-y instead of middle-mouse-key or Ctrl+Shift+V. Result: ctrl-y only pastes from emacs' kill ring, not from external selection.

Method 2: Unmap RET from `newline-and-indent`:

```
(add-hook 'lisp-mode-hook '(lambda ()
  (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline)))
```

It works for typing RET (no indent), but for middle-mouse-key or Ctrl+Shift+V auto-indent is applied anyway.

Comment: Do `^H m` and read about configuring `auto-fill-mode` or `^U 0 ESC X auto-fill-mode` to turn it OFF.

Comment: Having auto-fill-mode disabled doesn't help. The extra auto-indent can still be reproduced. My understanding is that, for the extra indents, RET - by default defines to newline-and-indent - is at work instead of auto-fill-mode ?

Answer (score 6):

Autoindentation occurs in emacs when the newline character is encountered. You can use `electric-indent-local-mode` and `electric-indent-mode` to toggle this setting.

From http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/03/29/automatic-electric-indentation/

> What’s little known is that Emacs 24.1 introduced a new global minor mode called electric-indent-mode. When enabled, typing certain characters(like newlines) triggers reindentation.

Comment: I'm running emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu, and turning off electric-indent-mode doesn't prevent the indentation. Even after *also* doing the add-hook suggested by @Zhang Weiwu.

Comment: `electric-indent-local-mode` worked for me.

Comment: This approach of blacklisting any mode that can play with buffer contents on paste seems like it would need more than just electric mode. Off the top of my head, at least there's abbrev mode and paredit.